# Problem with AJAX GET function inside PHP FUNCTION

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I got a while loop, and inside that loop i got another while loop that i only want to run after button.click

My javascript code inside profile.php:

```
$('.commentbtn').click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/functions.inc.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'offset': 0,
            'limit': 3
        },
        success: function(data)
        {}
    });
```

My php code inside functions.inc.php:

```
function getProfilePostModals($conn)
{
    $uid = $_SESSION['userId'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE uid=$uid AND type=1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($postrow = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $pid = $postrow['pid'];

        //// some code for the posts /////
        echo "<input id='opencomments".$pid."' class='commentbtn' type='button' value='Comment'>";

        if (isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])) {
            $commentssql = "SELECT * FROM postcomments WHERE pid=$pid";
            $commentsquery = mysqli_query($conn, $commentssql);

            while ($commentrow = $commentsquery->fetch_assoc())
            {
                //// some code for the comments that i want to run after "offset" and "limit" isset
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything was working fine before I started adding the `if(isset)`. 
But now the comments are not coming up anymore. What I want to do is to make a load on scroll function for the comments, I know its not complete code for that yet, I just try to see if I can get the isset to work first. Thank you in advance, I'm still learning.

**UPDATE:**
The functions.inc.php got more than 1 function inside it, and inside my profile.php I have this code to get everything to:

```
<?php include 'includes/functions.inc.php'; ?>
<?php getProfilePostModals($conn);?>
```

I don't know if this information helps or not.

** NEW UPDATE:**

getcomments.inc.php:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['offset'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];

$commentssql = "SELECT * FROM postcomments WHERE pid=$pid";
$commentsquery = mysqli_query($conn, $commentssql);
while ($row = $commentsquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $commentuid = $row['uid'];
    $pcid = $row['pcid'];
    $commentpid = $row['pid'];
    $commentdate = $row['date'];
    $comment = $row['postcomment'];

    $usersql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$commentuid";
    $userquery = mysqli_query($conn, $usersql);
    $userrow = $userquery->fetch_assoc();
    $commentimage = $userrow['imageUsers'];
    $ctusername = $userrow['uidUsers'];

    echo "<div id='deletecomment".$pcid."' class='deletecommentverify'>
    <form action='includes/deletecomment.inc.php' method='POST' runat='server' name='deletepost_form'>
        <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this comment?</h3>
        <input type='hidden' name='pcid' value='".$pcid."'>
        <button class='deletecommentbtn' type='submit' name='deletecomment_submit'>Yes</button>
        <input id='closedeletecomment".$pcid."' class='closedeletecomment' type='button' value='No'>
    </form>
</div>
    <div class='commentbox' id='commentbox".$pcid."'>
            <img class='usercommentimage' src='images/".$commentimage."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='commentuid' value='".$commentuid."'>
            <p><a href='profile.php'>".$ctusername." </a> ".$comment."</p>";
            if ($commentuid == $_SESSION['userId']) {
                echo "
            <span class='deletecommenticon' id='opendeletecomment".$pcid."'></span>";
            }
            echo "
            <div class='comment_info'>
                <span class='comment_count'>".$commentdate."</span>
            </div>

        </div>
        ";
}
}
```

And I made a test.php just to try it out with this code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
include 'includes/functions.inc.php';
include 'includes/like.inc.php';
include 'includes/getcomments.inc.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
if (!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Beautytrends</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mali|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/notext-logo.png">
</head>

<body>


  <input id='181' class='commentbtn' data-id='181' type='button' value='Comment'>
    <div id="profile-content">



    </div>



<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>


<script>



$(document).ready(function(){



                $('.commentbtn').click(function(){
                    var pid = $(this).attr("id")
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'test.php',
                        type: 'GET',

                        data: {
                            'offset': 0,
                            'limit': 3,
                            'pid' = pid

                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#profile-content').append(data);}


                        }

                    });
                });

            });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it's still not working. I tried to put 'includes/getcomments.inc.php?offset=0&limit=3&pid=181' in the browser and then everything comes up, so its like the ajax dont send the GET data to getcomments.

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: Done any debugging? What were the results? You seem to have spotted a symptom, but you haven't supplied any useful technical details which might point towards the cause. Do you understand how to debug PHP programs, and how to debug AJAX requests (using your browser's Developer Tools for the latter)? BTW is this really your code? Because you can't just stick an `<input...` in the middle of a PHP block like that, you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: _SMall Point_ `isset()` accepts multiple parameters and tests them with an AND :)

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are deveopling on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Mathias: It is always a bad idea to show us code that is not AS IS in the real page! All you will gate is comments or even answers about the mistakes that look like they are there

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky Did you not see `type: 'GET',`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky I thought the same, but jQuery doc states `It's appended to the url for GET-requests.` - so data should be fine.

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is my code, I just took away some parts that I know got nothing to do with the error. If I add everything it will be very much. And do you mean that I should remove "&&" and put AND instead?

Comment: @treyBake I'm sorry, I am new to this and still learning, my English is also not perfect, what will it say to address imminently?

Comment: @ADyson I just forgot to the input inside an echo in the description, I got it inside and echo in my code. And no, I don't know much about debugging.

Comment: You could try reformatting your code to:

    $('.commentbtn').click(function()
    {
        $post = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/functions.inc.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: "offset=0&limit=3",
            success: function(data)
            {}
        });

Comment: @jdavid05 that did not work.

Comment: Have you tried going to the url directly 'includes/functions.inc.php?offset=0&limit=3' and checking if the code works? It should give you an error message on what's causing the problems

Comment: @jdavid05 I tried that now. When i tried to put 'profile.php?offset=0&limit=3' it all worked, so i tried changing the url: to profile.php but still not working, but i think thats maybe what i should have there since i have 'included' the functions.inc.php inside the profile.php

Comment: as i see in the updated question the `'includes/functions.inc.php'` have only functions, while the rendering happen in the `profile.php`. if so, you cannot expect something to render when you call the `functions.inc.php`

Comment: Maybe change '<?php include 'includes/functions.inc.php'; ?>' to '<?php include 'includes/functions.inc.php?offset=0&limit=3'; ?>'

Comment: also, @YosefTukachinsky is correct

Comment: I think I see what's going wrong here. You want to do an infinite scroll but you are  calling your ajax from a functions file that stores multiple functions. You will need to separate the files so your ajax page can be separate (have its own HTML to append to a div). See this URL for some helpful info [link](https://phppot.com/php/how-to-create-facebook-like-infinite-scroll-pagination-using-php-and-jquery/)

Comment: @jdavid05 the ajax is in the bottom of the profile.php and the functions.inc.php is just full of php functions. So i should make an own php file for this function instead of having it with all the other php functions inside functions.inc.php ? And yes my goal is to make an infinite scroll.

Comment: If you put your function on a separate page then you wont have a problem with the fact that you already include the functions page. So, yeah, if you put your function on another page you can load all the html from that page. Then change what your function returns to something like: success: function(data){$("#post-list").append(data);} so the html gets appended from your new function page to the item with id "post-list" or whatever id is associated with where you want the data to be appended. Honestly though, the link I gave you should accomplish this for you

Comment: @jdavid05 Will it then work that i just take the code to get the comments and put in a seperate php file, and append the data to #commentscontent?

Comment: @jdavid05 I made an update, still not working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208213/discussion-between-jdavid05-and-mathias-hermansen).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my comments and suggestions to help solve the issues you're having.

> I don't understand what you're trying to do here, but `$(this)` refers to the button itself which doesn't seem like what you need. I don't see that you're actually using the variable either.

```
$('.commentbtn').click(function()
{
    $post = $(this);
```

> You need to do something with the response you receive. Until you get everything working I would recommend the following. Then you can just check the browser console for any output that was sent from the server.

```
success: function(data)
        {console.log(data);}
```

> You're referring to the wrong variable name, `$row` should be `$postrow`. This is going to cause an error because `['pid']` index doesn't exist.

```
while ($postrow = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $pid = $row['pid'];
```

> For this bit, you need to do something if the variables are not set, such as send back a response, otherwise you'll never know what went wrong. Also, as stated in the comments, NEVER access user provided data directly without first validating/sanitizing it and use prepared statements for your queries.

```
if (isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])) {
    $commentssql = "SELECT * FROM postcomments WHERE pid=$pid";
    $commentsquery = mysqli_query($conn, $commentssql);

    while ($commentrow = $commentsquery->fetch_assoc())
    {
        //// some code for the comments that i want to run after "offset" and "limit" isset
    }
} else {
    echo "Expected $_GET values not received";
}
```

> Finally, you have no way of knowing if your queries fail because you have no error handling. This is something you need to implement into your code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you want to do is load jquery in your head section rather than the middle of the page:

```
<head>
    <title>Beautytrends</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mali|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/notext-logo.png">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then you can replace your button

`<input id='181' class='commentbtn' data-id='181' type='button' value='Comment'>`

with

```
<div class="button-holder">
  <!-- We set the initial value 1 because we want only 1 results at a time -->
  <input type="hidden" id="result_no" value="1">
  <input type="button" class="button btn-md btn-success load-button" id="loadmore" value="Load More Results">
</div>
```

The benefit of this button setup is it stores a variable saying which record to load (result_no) which you can use in your query.

Your javascript can be replaced by this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#loadmore").click(function(){
  loadmore();
 });
});

function loadmore()
{
 var val = document.getElementById("result_no").value;
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'load_more.php',
 data: {
  getresult:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
  var content = document.getElementById("profile-content");
  content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML+response;

  // We increase the value by 1 because we limit the results by 1
  document.getElementById("result_no").value = Number(val)+1;
 }
 });
}
</script>
```

Offset is replaced by result_no so your other code will only change slightly. Make sure this is its own php file named load_more.php (if you want to change the name of the file change it in the javascript as well):

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['result_no'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';
    $pid = $_POST['result_no'];

$commentssql = "SELECT * FROM postcomments WHERE pid=$pid";
$commentsquery = mysqli_query($conn, $commentssql);
while ($row = $commentsquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $commentuid = $row['uid'];
    $pcid = $row['pcid'];
    $commentpid = $row['pid'];
    $commentdate = $row['date'];
    $comment = $row['postcomment'];

    $usersql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$commentuid";
    $userquery = mysqli_query($conn, $usersql);
    $userrow = $userquery->fetch_assoc();
    $commentimage = $userrow['imageUsers'];
    $ctusername = $userrow['uidUsers'];

    echo "<div id='deletecomment".$pcid."' class='deletecommentverify'>
    <form action='includes/deletecomment.inc.php' method='POST' runat='server' name='deletepost_form'>
        <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this comment?</h3>
        <input type='hidden' name='pcid' value='".$pcid."'>
        <button class='deletecommentbtn' type='submit' name='deletecomment_submit'>Yes</button>
        <input id='closedeletecomment".$pcid."' class='closedeletecomment' type='button' value='No'>
    </form>
</div>
    <div class='commentbox' id='commentbox".$pcid."'>
            <img class='usercommentimage' src='images/".$commentimage."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='commentuid' value='".$commentuid."'>
            <p><a href='profile.php'>".$ctusername." </a> ".$comment."</p>";
            if ($commentuid == $_SESSION['userId']) {
                echo "
            <span class='deletecommenticon' id='opendeletecomment".$pcid."'></span>";
            }
            echo "
            <div class='comment_info'>
                <span class='comment_count'>".$commentdate."</span>
            </div>

        </div>
        ";
}
}
```

I've never used MySQL so I can't test it with that. However, this works with a different query using Postgres so it should work fine here if your query is valid.

Any problems, just let me know. This also doesn't solve your injection attack issues but you can solve those later.